Why is parameter allowDiskUse is not working in my JasperReport using MongoDB aggregation query
I've created a Jasper Report using an aggregation pipeline from a MongoDB data source and everything was working properly with small amount of data but now that we have more and more data this query raises the following error :
Command failed with error 292 (QueryExceededMemoryLimitNoDiskUseAllowed): 'PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.' on server localhost:1221.
I don't want to filter on less data that I already filter on as I need to export daily data.
The problem is that I already use the option allowDiskUse:true, I checked other posts and I tried with or without quotes, with or without braces.
When I do the similar query in Studio3T to test it without "allowDiskUse": true I have the error and with it I don't have the error. So why it isn't taken into account in my Jasper report.
The only differences I can see is that in my report the query is like this :
<queryString language="MongoDbQuery">
        <![CDATA[{
   "runCommand":{
      "aggregate":"XXX",
      "pipeline":[
         {
            "$match":{
               ...

            }
         },{
            "$project":{
              ...
    }
  },
   {
    $project: {
      ...
    }
  },{ $group: {
            ...}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ...
    }
  },
  {
            "$project":{
              ...
              }, 
            {
            "$unwind":{
               ...
            }
          },
          { $sort: { ... } }, 
          { $group: {
            ...
    }
  },
  
   {
    $project: {
      ..
                }
    }
  },{ $group: {
            ... }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ...
    }
  },
  {
            "$unwind":{
               ...
            }
         },
  
         {
            "$project":{
               ...
            }
         },
         
         {
            "$unwind": ...
         }, 
         {
            "$project":{
               ...}
         }, 
        
         {
            "$group":{
               ...
         },
         {
            "$project":{
               ...}
         },
         {
            "$project":{
               ...}
            }
         },{
            "$project":{
            ...}
            }
         },
         {
            "$sort":{
            ...}
            }
         } 
      ],
      allowDiskUse:true
   }
}]]>
    </queryString>

whereas in studio 3T it's :
   db.XXX.aggregate([
    
    {
            "$match":{
               ...

            }
         },{
            "$project":{
              ...
    }
  },
   {
    $project: {
      ...
    }
  },{ $group: {
            ...}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ...
    }
  },
  {
            "$project":{
              ...
              }, 
            {
            "$unwind":{
               ...
            }
          },
          { $sort: { ... } }, 
          { $group: {
            ...
    }
  },
  
   {
    $project: {
      ..
                }
    }
  },{ $group: {
            ... }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ...
    }
  },
  {
            "$unwind":{
               ...
            }
         },
  
         {
            "$project":{
               ...
            }
         },
         
         {
            "$unwind": ...
         }, 
         {
            "$project":{
               ...}
         }, 
        
         {
            "$group":{
               ...
         },
         {
            "$project":{
               ...}
         },
         {
            "$project":{
               ...}
            }
         },{
            "$project":{
            ...}
            }
         },
         {
            "$sort":{
            ...}
            }
         }
      ],
     { "allowDiskUse": true }
    )

The option
     { "allowDiskUse": true }

should have solved the problem but I keep having the error message even with this option
